# Flask date not set at creation but is set at update

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

views.py

```
@app.route('/new', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def new():
    form = StudentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            flash('All fields are required.')
            return render_template('form.html', action = 'new', form = form)
        else:
            student = students(
            request.form['first_name'], request.form['last_name'], \
            request.form['date_of_birth'], \
            request.form['date_of_join'], request.form['address']
            db.session.add(student)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
    return render_template('form.html', action = url_for('new'), form = form)


@app.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def edit(id):
    item = students.query.get(id)
    form = StudentForm(obj=item)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            item = students.query.get(id)
            form = StudentForm(obj=item)
            return render_template('form.html', action = url_for('edit',id = id), form = form)
        else:
            form.populate_obj(item)
            db.session.add(item)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
    return render_template('form.html', action = url_for('edit',id = id), form = form)
```

models.py

```
class students(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "students"
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    date_of_birth = db.Column(db.Date)
    date_of_join = db.Column(db.Date)
    address = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

forms.py

```
class StudentForm(Form):
    first_name = TextField("First Name:")
    last_name =  TextField("Last Name:")
    date_of_birth = DateField("Date of Birth:", format='%m/%d/%Y')
    date_of_join = DateField("Date of Joining:", format='%m/%d-%Y')
    address = TextAreaField("Address:")
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

All other fields are added to the database while adding new item, but the date is not stored. I cant find what the problem actually is. The date field is stored during edit if i use form.validate() for form validation. And if i use form.validate_on_submit() the date field is not stored while adding or editing...

Comment: `request.form('date_of_birth')` probably raises a `TypeError` about `request.form` not being callable. Odds are this is just code you threw together for this question. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41227832/edit) the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I dont get any errors. As i have only added the part i have doubt. The code runs fine and stores date to database on creation, only the date is not added. But the date is stored to the database on edit...

Comment: I have form = StudentForm() on my views.py so no TypeError..

Comment: Ok i got it working by adding the following before db.session.add(item)form.populate_obj(student)